# How to convert to floating point (from HEX String)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion, hex, pyodbc

I just learned python for couple of weeks and I have no idea on the data type converting. So, I have a very big data contains something like this, which I imported from SQL.

```
i='0x9406920691068F068D068A0688068506820680067E067D067D067D067B067906760674066E066A066806650665066506650669066F067D069206AD06CD06EE060F072.........'
```

I imported the SQl data to python using this code (which I acquired from previous questions)

```
import pyodbc
from struct import pack, unpack

conn_str = (
          r'Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};'
          r'Server=Laptop;'
          r'Database=Access;'
          r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
          r'CHARSET=UTF8;'
        )

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cnxn.add_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_VARBINARY, hexToString) #to copy the varbinary
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

def convert_hex_to_int(n:int, interval:int):
    splitted = [hex(n)[2:][i:i+interval] for i in range(0, len(hex(n)[2:]), interval)]
    return [int(hex(unpack('<H', pack('>H', int(i, 10)))[0]), 10) for i in splitted]

cursor.execute(query)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Based on that, if I type `print(row)`, it generates result

```
'0x9406920691068F068D068A0688068506820680067E067D067D067D067B06790676....'
```

when I type `print(type(row))` the data type is `<class 'pyodbc.Row'>`

when I use the function `print(convert_hex_to_int(row, 4))` to get the results by taking 4 bytes at the time and fllip it, it generates error:

> TypeError: 'pyodbc.Row' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

The plan is to get `'0x94069206..'` to be `0694 0692` and convert it to int/floating point to be `1684 1682` and so on.

Comment: Are you passing `row` as the first argument to your `convert_hex_to_int` function? If so, then be aware that `fetchone()` will always return a `pyodbc.Row` object, never a primitive type (like `str`), even if the `Row` object only contains one value. If your query only returns one column then use `fetchval()` instead of `fetchone()` and you will get the value as a native Python type/object.

Comment: oh yeah it becomes string! thankyou. And could you help me in converting the string to int? as the generated string is '0x9406....' and when i tried to type it like this: row = cursor.fetchval() then row = int(row),
I get the error
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x9406920691068F068D068A068806850..'

Comment: `fetchval()` is returning the string representation of the entire varbinary column as a `str`. Simply doing `int(row)` is not doing any of the splitting and iteration that you have coded into your `convert_hex_to_int` function.

Comment: Thankyou it helps a lot!

Comment: Hi @gordthompson, as the .fetchval() returns the value for only 1 column, how do I get the values of the whole rows?